Cannot use gvenzl/oracle-free oracle free image in Github actions
I have a github actions repository and I would like it to connect with an Oracle database, containerised using Oracle Database Free Container / Docker images image.
I would like to perform additional initialization of the database using a  *.sql file under /container-entrypoint-initdb.d, as indicated in the image description.
However, I get the following error when I try to build it. More specifically, I get the error:
Error 45 initializing SQL*Plus

My workflow.yml contains:
services:

      # Oracle service (label used to access the service container)
      oracle:

        # Docker Hub image (feel free to change the tag "latest" to any other available one)
        image: gvenzl/oracle-free:latest

        # Provide passwords and other environment variables to container
        env:
          ORACLE_RANDOM_PASSWORD: true
          APP_USER: my_user
          APP_USER_PASSWORD: password_i_should_change

        # Forward Oracle port
        ports:
          - 1521:1521

        # Provide healthcheck script options for startup
        options: >-
          --health-cmd healthcheck.sh
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 10
        volumes:
          - my-init.sql:/container-entrypoint-initdb.d/my-init.sql:ro

As stated in the image documentation.
On the other hand, the file /container-entrypoint-initdb.d/my-init.sql, included in the repository's root has the following lines:
alter session set container=freepdb1;
CREATE USER TEST IDENTIFIED BY test QUOTA UNLIMITED ON USERS;
GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE TO TEST;

I do not find the problem. Any help is welcome.
Thanks
UPDATE. Following the first suggestion given by Azzem, I have tried with:
name: Build and test of Java Project
 
on: [push]
 
jobs:
 build:
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
   timeout-minutes: 6
   services:

      # Oracle service (label used to access the service container)
      oracle:

        # Docker Hub image (feel free to change the tag "latest" to any other available one)
        image: gvenzl/oracle-free:latest
       
        # Provide passwords and other environment variables to container
        env:
          ORACLE_RANDOM_PASSWORD: true
          APP_USER: my_user
          APP_USER_PASSWORD: password_i_should_change

        # Forward Oracle port
        ports:
          - 1521:1521

        # Provide healthcheck script options for startup
        options: >-
          --name oracle
          --health-cmd healthcheck.sh
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 10
        # volumes:
        #   - my-init.sql:/container-entrypoint-initdb.d/my-init.sql:ro
   steps:
     - uses: actions/checkout@v2
     - name: Set up JDK 21
       uses: actions/setup-java@v1
       with:
         java-version: 21
     - name: Setup timezone
       uses: zcong1993/setup-timezone@master
       with:
          timezone: Europe/Madrid
     - name: Restart_container
        # Restart container after volumes have been checked out
       uses: docker://docker
       with:
          args: docker restart oracle
     - name: Create database
       run:  bash ./create_tables.sh
       shell: bash 
     - name: Build with Maven
       run: mvn -B test --file pom.xml

where the first lines of the create_tables.sh filer are:
export ORACLE_SID=FREE
export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/23ai/dbhomeFree
export ORAENV_ASK=NO
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin
$PATH/sqlplus -S my_user/password_i_should_change <<SQL
whenever sqlerror exit 2;
...

I have tried both with SID FREE and FREEPDB1, but I get the same error message line 5: /opt/oracle/product/23ai/dbhomeFree/bin/sqlplus: No such file or directory. Any idea?
Thanks!
UPDATE 2:  following steps at https://github.com/gvenzl/setup-oracle-free:
name: Build and test of Java Project
 
on: [push]
 
jobs:
 test:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  timeout-minutes: 6
  steps:
     - uses: actions/checkout@v4
     - uses: gvenzl/setup-oracle-free@v1
       with:
          app-user: myUser
          app-user-password: myPwd
          startup-scripts: ${{ github.workspace }}/scripts
     - name: Set up JDK 21
       uses: actions/setup-java@v1
       with:
         java-version: 21
     - name: Setup timezone
       uses: zcong1993/setup-timezone@master
       with:
          timezone: Europe/Madrid
     - name: Build with Maven
       run: mvn -B test --file pom.xml

I got the error:
Error: can only create exec sessions on running containers: container state improper

UPDATE3: Thank you very much again. That works with docker. The point is that I need to create a database with concrete tables and, later, connect to it from JDBC. It seems that, after creating a user/password the login is denied, using:
url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:FREE
user=myUser
password=myPwd

Although I create the user/password in the workflow.yml, it seems that it does not work. I also try to create them in the init.sql file (I have tried both with FREE and FREEPDB1 service names), but with no success:
ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER=FREE;
CREATE USER myUser IDENTIFIED BY myPwd QUOTA UNLIMITED ON USERS;
GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE TO myUser ;
CREATE SCHEMA  AUTHORIZATION myUser ; 
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = myUser;

CREATE TABLE ...

Do you have any idea? Thank you very much

Apparently, this isn't possible with GHA services at the moment as the files from your repo will only be available after your checkout step whereas the service container will start before that. See https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/42127 for more details. There are some workaround mentioned in there. The simple one would be to restart the service container after your checkout step. See https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/42127#discussioncomment-7591609. Alternatively, you may run container in the workflow using docker run or use docker compose for services.

Hi Azeem, Thank you very much for your response. However, I still have a similar problem.  I restart the container and try to execute a SQL command with a SQL file but I get the error with sql*Plus:
/opt/oracle/product/23ai/dbhomeFree/bin/sqlplus: No such file or directory 

In your updated workflow, the checkout step is missing or omitted. The indentation is a bit off too. Can you please specify that? Please add the complete error also.

Sorry for the indentation...I have updated and put the complete workflow.yml file.

Thanks! The actions/checkout@v2 is very old. You should be using the latest one i.e. actions/checkout@v4. Now, from your workflow and script, it looks like it may have worked (need to verify though). But, the error message that you shared earlier i.e. sql*Plus: /opt/oracle/product/23ai/dbhomeFree/bin/sqlplus: No such file or directory seems to be coming from your create_tables.sh script. ORACLE_HOME env var is being set to /opt/oracle/product/23ai/dbhomeFree. What is this path here?

I just went through the complete docs (https://hub.docker.com/r/gvenzl/oracle-free) and it seems like you may not need everything described in there. From your script, it looks like you just need an up oracle instance to run some queries. Are you sure you need that init SQL script?

I just found https://github.com/gvenzl/setup-oracle-free action and it does everything you need. You don't need to set up services yourself. It's simpler and straightforward and from the same author. See https://github.com/gvenzl/setup-oracle-free?tab=readme-ov-file#init-scripts section if you really need to run init scripts from the files in your repo.

Thank you very much again....I was trying to execute an init script in a more complicated way...however, although I follow the indications of the new page, I get another error: "Error: can only create exec sessions on running containers: container state improper" :(

I put 10 checks every 20 seconds but in 200s the database is not initialised (error Database failed to start on time). I don't know what to try anymore. Thank you very much for your help.

It's working for me. Please see this workflow and its run. I used the docker instead of podman (default). See https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/10860450070/workflow#L17. Also, you don't need to any separate step to check if the container is up. It's already covered as part of that action. Check its inputs for more details.

Thanks Aeem. I have included UPDATE 3.

You're welcome! Have you run this setup locally using docker and sqlplus client? How are you installing sqlplus client in your workflow? It was not there initially but you were using it in your script.

I think it is not required to install sqlplus client since in "https://hub.docker.com/r/gvenzl/oracle-free" it states "The *.sql, *.sql.gz and .sql.zip files will be executed in SQLPlus as the SYS user connected to the Oracle instance (FREE)."

Try oracledb instead of localhost.

nothing (I have tried with "oracle" since in my workflow.yml I put "oracle" as container-name)

Please provide a minimal, reproducible example as a public repo including some sample code accessing the DB. That would be helpful to debug it.

thank you! Here you can find the  repository https://github.com/PRBD2324/oracle23Stack

Please check your repo. The init/startup issues have been resolved. You may proceed with the rest of the setup i.e. DB creation, users, etc. See https://github.com/PRBD2324/oracle23Stack/actions/runs/10885166905.

I found your instructions very helpful. I have now realized my mistakes. In the case of logging, I needed to explicitly create the user in the start up script as part of the FREEPDB1 container.
Secondly, I had to consider that the schema in oracle matches the user's name.

FYI: Hi, I just published https://github.com/iamazeem/setup-oracle-instant-client-action to set up the Oracle Instant Client (e.g. sqlplus CLI tool) on GHA runners. For similar use cases as yours, I usually find it quite useful to experiment with a relevant CLI tool first before moving on to code. It usually is much faster to make sure something is working without the code and the same can then easily be replicated later in the code as well. Hope, you'll find it helpful too. All the best!

Apparently, this isn't possible with GHA service containers at the moment as the files from your repo will only be available after your checkout step whereas the service container will start before that. See this GitHub discussion How to mount file from repository to the service container's volume? for more details on this.
There are some workarounds mentioned in there. The simple one would be to restart the service container after your checkout step. See this comment on the same thread.
Alternatively, you may run container in the workflow using docker run or use docker compose for services.

However, I found this https://github.com/gvenzl/setup-oracle-free action and it does everything you need. You don't need to set up services yourself. It's simpler and straightforward; and, is from the same author.
I've tested it on ubuntu-latest runner and this is working fine for me.
Here are the relevant workflow steps:
- name: Checkout
  uses: actions/checkout@v4

- name: Setup Oracle container
  uses: gvenzl/setup-oracle-free@v1
  with:
    container-runtime: docker
    app-user: app_user
    app-user-password: app_user_password
    setup-scripts: ${{ github.workspace }}/scripts

- name: Check Oracle container logs for errors
  run: |
    docker container ls
    docker container logs oracledb | tee -a /tmp/oracledb.log
    if grep 'ERROR' /tmp/oracledb.log >/dev/null; then
      echo "[ERR] Something went wrong!"
      echo "[ERR] See above logs for more details."
      exit 1
    fi

The checkout step should come first in the sequence of steps. For the input parameter setup-scripts, the respective directory should be available to be mounted as a volume.
Currently, the container run logs are not being dumped to stdout/stderr. That's why I had to dump its logs to a file and filter those for any errors in a subsequent step.
Apart from that, according to the docs, the url in your configuration i.e.:
url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:FREE

should be:
url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/FREEPDB1

As mentioned under ORACLE_DATABASE env var docs, FREEPDB1 is created by default. FREEPDB1 is a service name, not an SID - observe the difference between : and / in the url.

Given above information, your create_database.sql script will look like this:
ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER = FREEPDB1;
CREATE USER myUser IDENTIFIED BY myPwd QUOTA UNLIMITED ON USERS;

GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE TO myUser;
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO myUser;
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = myUser;

And, your complete .properties file will be:
url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/FREEPDB1
user=myUser
password=myPwd
schema=myUser

Observe that the database username/password (myUser/myPwd) is different from the application one (app-user/app-user-name i.e. app_user/app_user_password).

Here are some miscellaneous points:

Update actions actions/checkout@v2 and actions/setup-java@v1 to their respective latest versions. In addition, you can configure dependabot to automate this. See Keeping your actions up to date with Dependabot for more details.

actions/setup-java supports caching of maven dependencies. You might want to use that to speed up your workflow.

https://github.com/zcong1993/setup-timezone has not been updated in a long time. You can simply set TZ env var instead to set the timezone.
env:
  TZ: Europe/Madrid

You can set it at workflow, job, or step level according to your use case.


